# Passing function as parameter in Filter dplyr in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

Hi All This is a general question regaring my Shiny dashboard 
I am trying to pass function under dplyr - filter

I am getting error message 
Warning: Error in get: object 'f' of mode 'function' was not found

```
library(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

Quarter <- c("Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q1","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy17Q4","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q2","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q3","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy18Q4","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1","Fy19Q1")
QuarterInNum <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)
OperatingGroupDesc <- ("Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Communications, Media & Technology","Financial Services","Financial Services","Financial Services","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Health & Public Service","Products","Products","Products","Resources","Resources","Resources")
RiskTierDesc <- c("Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal","Above Normal","High","Normal")
Freq <- c(64,13,225,86,11,273,52,6,125,158,17,325,87,5,213,97,38,244,106,12,343,52,4,106,131,27,358,84,6,226,118,16,251,110,15,297,56,7,118,191,18,385,81,13,233,97,13,255,102,8,281,57,5,95,144,29,367,71,6,197,88,7,249,91,10,313,66,4,108,168,18,359,68,7,218,105,4,329,98,8,428,52,5,116,164,25,468,100,4,300,144,9,303,122,15,435,65,2,144,199,26,440,68,9,269,118,8,297,100,8,354,71,7,134,195,22,374,72,11,292,68,3,352,106,10,369,69,2,135,142,17,459,93,9,302)
FreqPercent <- c(21,4,75,23,3,74,28,3,68,32,3,65,29,2,70,26,10,64,23,3,74,32,2,65,25,5,69,27,2,72,31,4,65,26,4,70,31,4,65,32,3,65,25,4,71,27,4,70,26,2,72,36,3,61,27,5,68,26,2,72,26,2,72,22,2,76,37,2,61,31,3,66,23,2,74,24,1,75,18,1,80,30,3,67,25,4,71,25,1,74,32,2,66,21,3,76,31,1,68,30,4,66,20,3,78,28,2,70,22,2,77,33,3,63,33,4,63,19,3,78,16,1,83,22,2,76,33,1,66,23,3,74,23,2,75)

Data <- data.frame(Quarter,QuarterInNum,OperatingGroupDesc,RiskTierDesc,Freq,FreqPercent)
```

UI PART

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu( selectInput("app", 
                             "Select:", 
                             choices = c("","Risk tier by Count","Risk tier by TR","Risk tier by TCNR"), 
                             selected = NULL, 
                             multiple = F,
                             selectize = F,
                             width = NULL,
                             size = NULL)),
    sliderTextInput("Quarter","Select Quarter:",
                    choices =  c("Fy17Q1","Fy17Q2","Fy17Q3","Fy17Q4","Fy18Q1","Fy18Q2"),
                    selected =  c("Fy17Q2","Fy18Q1")),
    selectInput(inputId="variable", label="OG to show:", 
                choices=c("All","CMT","FS","HPS","PRD","RES"), selected = NULL, multiple = F,selectize = F),    

dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(  

      tableOutput('table')

    )))
```

SERVER PART

```
server <- function(input, output) {

XX <- reactive(input$app)  
  YY <- reactive(input$variable)


  dataInput <- reactive({
    #dataframe <- GroupFreq
    qfrom <- Data$QuarterInNum[match(input$Quarter[1], as.character(Data$Quarter))]
    qto <- Data$QuarterInNum[match(input$Quarter[2], as.character(Data$Quarter))]
    test <- Data[Data$QuarterInNum %in% seq(from=qfrom,to=qto),]
    print(test)
    #test()
  })



}

KK1 <- reactive({BB <- if((XX() != "") && (YY() != "All")){Filter(dataInput(),((OperatingGroupDesc == as.character(YY()))))}
AA1 <- data.frame(BB1)
return(AA1)})

output$table <- renderTable(KK1()) 
#output$table <- renderTable(dataInput()) # to test the dataInput()
  #output$table <- renderTable(Data) # to test if i am getting the table

} 

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server),launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Need the table output as per the OG selected from the select input

Answer (score 0):

Your `server`-function is totally wonky. Please see e.g. this tutorial (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html) for how it should be structured.

Secondly, the function `Filter` (with uppercase F) is not the `dplyr` filter (which uses lowercase f) and its first argument is most likely `NULL`, not a data.frame.

Your `f` (in the `selectInput` call) is not "false". Short-hand booleans are uppercase (`F` or `T`) and should be **avoided as they can be redefined**.